# changing themes dynamically using masterpages in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

I have created a master page and put in them in a drop box having 2 themes 
professional and funky how can I change them dynamically and save the changes on master page 
I have already created a base class, I just cant understand the code.

```
using System;
using System.Web;
public partial class SiteMaster:System.Web.UI.MasterPage
{
    private string _theme = "";
    public string Theme
    {
        get { return _theme; }
        set { _theme = value; }
    }
}
public class BasePage:System.Web.UI.Page
{}
```

Comment: Check this first: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/363006/Master-Pages-and-Themes#taspnet

Comment: Right, you can change theme from code behind according to your drop box.

Comment: Master page is layout page for you web application. Any page fills in content will have the theme accordingly.

Comment: It will be straight to put it in your master page.

Comment: Can you paste errors?

Comment: there is no changes in the theme is there any editting to be done in the code you had send?

Comment: Configuration config = WebConfigurationManager.OpenWebConfiguration("~/");
        //Get the required section of the web.config file by using configuration object.
        PagesSection pages = (PagesSection)config.GetSection("system.web/pages");
        //Update the new values.
        pages.Theme = DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text.ToString();
        //save the changes by using Save() method of configuration object.

Comment: i dont know the code in between

Comment: Set this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.page.theme(v=vs.110).aspx in your dropdownlist post back.